# Countdown timer in Javascript shows the old data too after new data is entered

Tags: javascript, html

So here I am writing a countdown timer with HTML and Javascript. But I am having an issue with it. It looks like it doesn't ''forget'' the old input data and shows both old and new almost at the same time after I click the Calculate button.

My code seems to work but the problem is that when I enter a new date it shows both old and new timer. For example, if I enter December 7, 2020 it will show 1 day (some minutes and seconds, whatever) and after that if I enter December 8, 2020 within each second it shows 2 days and then it suddenly changes to 1 day then changes to 2 days etc. If I enter another date it will quickly show all three timers. how do I fix this?
I thought that the old information was left and I tried adding a statement to clear the "res" part but it still does the same. I don't know  what is the reason.

```js
function calculate() {
  var until_date = new Date(document.getElementById("input_date").value).getTime();
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var today = new Date().getTime();
    var d = until_date - today;
    var days = Math.floor(d / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hr = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var min = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var sec = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = days + "d " + hr + "h " + min + "m " + sec + "s ";

    if (d < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "DONE";
    }
  }, 1000);

}
```

```html
<p>Please select a date: <input id="input_date" type="date"></p>
<button id='calulate' onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<p id="res"></p>
```

Comment: it's still the same if I add ```clearInterval(x)``` in the beginning of the function :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the interval variable outside the function and clear the interval when the function is called again outside the loop.

Otherwise each function call you will be creating a new interval which will run parallel to the previous one.

```
var x;
function calculate() {
    clearInterval(x);
    var until_date = new Date(document.getElementById("input_date").value).getTime();
    x = setInterval(function () {
        var today = new Date().getTime();
        var d = until_date - today;
        var days = Math.floor(d / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hr = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var min = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var sec = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = days + "d " + hr + "h " + min + "m " + sec + "s ";

        if (d < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "DONE";
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works! I tried writing ```clearInterval(x);``` in the beginning but it of course didn't work. That's a good solution, thank you! :)